# Maintain consistent plot region for Graphics3D in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, bounding-box, graphics3d

I am trying to use `Animate` in conjunction with `Graphics3D` to make a list of vectors that have oscillating lengths. Basically, a list of random 3D vectors are plotted originating from the origin. Then the length of the vector is controlled with a cosine function with a random phase.

For example,

```
randomVec[r_] := r*Normalize@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]
vecs = Table[randomVec[i], {i, 10^2}];
hues = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 10^2}];
rans = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 10^2}];

Animate[
    Graphics3D[
        Table[{Hue[hues[[i]]], 
              Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 
              vecs[[i]] + Cos[\[Eta] + rans[[i]]*Pi]*vecs[[i]]}, 
              Scaled[0.007]]]}, {i, 10^2}],
     Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
     ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, Pi}],
{\[Eta], 0, 2*Pi}]
```

However, when I run this code, the origin of the animation seems to bounce around within the viewing frame. How can I force `Graphics3D` to use the exact same viewing box for every time that it is called within `Animate`?

Also this code is probably inefficient so any tips about how to make it animate more smoothly would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing to try in your case is to add a

```
 PlotRange->{{xmin, xmax},{ymin, ymax},{zmin, zmax}}
```

option.

It will control the size of the cube independently of the computed
data.

You may also want to look at options  `BoxRatios` and `SphericalRegion` for nice scaling of the result.

Comment: Great, together ,`PlotRange` and `SphericalRegion` make it look great. Now I just want to try to smooth out the animation...

Comment: Animate is great to quickly build an interactive animation. The trouble is that it reduces the computation resolution for speed among other things. If you want to produce a final, smooth animation, you might need to precalculate it, and there are several ways. It is worth another question, and I suggest you ask it at mathematica.stackexchange where many experts are available.